# Curved arrow linking flow diagram

Tags: arrows

I would like to draw something like this:

A ---> B ---> C and then have a curved arrow underneath going from A to C (and I will need to have a superscript on all the arrows to include a label).

I understand that this is possible with the xyarray package? But all of the examples on here seem much more complicated than the simple case that I want.

Can anybody help?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's also very simple with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A\rar{u}\arrow[red, bend right]{rr}[black,swap]{\varphi}  & B \rar{v}  & C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I made an edit only to fix the code markup. Nice answer!

Comment: Thanks :o) What was the problem?

Comment: the first line was set as ordinary text instead of code; nothing huge.

Comment: Must have been really out of my mind…

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, is there a way to reduce white space underneath the diagram so I can continue text without an overly large gap?

Comment: I've just tested, and it seems this is due to some other code in your file. I have no gap. Could you post a code showing the gap?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible with Xy, and is fairly simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix{
    A \ar[r] \ar@/_0.4cm/[rr] & B \ar[r] & C
}\]
\end{document}
```

Just as in a `matrix` or `array` environment, the content of an `xymatrix` is interpreted as a grid, with `&` separating entries and `\\` separating rows. `\ar` is the command for an arrow: `[r]` indicates that it points to the right.

The most complicated part is the curved arrow: starting with `\ar[rr]` (an arrow pointing two grid entries to the right), the syntax `@/_0.4cm/` signals to curve it downwards by 0.4 cm.

Output:

[image]

Then, you can label your arrows with superscripts and subscripts: `\ar[r]^f` typesets *f* above the arrow, and `\ar[r]_g` typesets *g* below the arrow. (If you use arrows pointing other directions, this will change: technically, `^` is used to put the label on the left side of the arrowhead, and `_` on the right side.)